# android start activity from service without using .FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android, service, android-activity, start-activity

I have a service which is making a call to a webserver from 30 to 30 seconds. If a certain value is returned i need to start a specific activity. the problem is for starting an activity from service I need to set intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

By doing this, the activity is launched but it is closed after 3-4 seconds and the application keeps is normal flow.

how can I add the new activity to the top of stack?

Comment: for Starting an Activity from service  need `Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND` flag

Comment: Something else is causing it to close after 3-4s. It's nothing to do with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i was calling the service in the launch of the application just for test. but if I navigate in my app after the 30 seconds, the new activity is brought to the front correctly.